# How to report suicidal comments on YouTube?

Tags: youtube, comments

As well as contacting authorities, what option should I click?

Answer (score -1):

> ### Suicide and self-injury
>
> Content that promotes self-harm or is intended
> to shock or disgust users is not allowed on YouTube. **We do allow** users
> to post content discussing their experiences with depression, self
> harm, or other mental health issues.
>
> ### What to do if you see this content
>
> If you come across content in which
> someone expresses suicidal thoughts or is engaging in self-harm,
> please contact local authorities and **flag the video** to bring it to our
> immediate attention. We reach out to these individuals with resources,
> and work with suicide prevention agencies to provide assistance when
> possible.
>
> **https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2802245?hl=en**

[image: 0]

Note that some people are of the opinion that this is not the appropriate path to follow (see e.g. this **[Concerned About Reporting Options for Suicidal Users](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube-creators/ahoai04Aq0c)** Google Product Forum post), but that does not change what Google recommends.